# Newline at top of PHP output

Tags: php, smarty

I have a strange problem about an additional line above my PHP output.

I'm using the Smarty template engine for formatting my output on a webpage. After I programmed a API connection, I get a newline above the output of the added subpage. Of course, I googled this problem. What I've tried so far:

- deleting all newlines at the end of all files and saving them again as UTF-8 *without* BOM
- *auto_prepend_file* in php.ini is set to nothing
- deleting the Smarty cache, turn caching off

One other strange thing is that if I test the program on my local PC (using XAMPP), I get the newline on *every* page. But when I test the system on my customers live server, only the affected API-page gets this newline. PHP warnings (E_ALL) appear above the newline.

Anyone got a idea that I haven't tried yet?

Comment: Have you looked for any output before `<html>` is echo'ed? Do not close PHP tag if it's only PHP code.

Comment: Can you share some code snippets? The controller that's rendering the template, and the template itself, maybe?

Comment: Sometimes omitting the `?>` tags helps.

Comment: There is no output before <html>, except the documenttype (which I used previously without errors). I removed all closing PHP tags, nothing changed. I'll prepare the source to show you, brb.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone got a idea that I haven't tried yet?

Well, as we cannot see the code, *and while this is not an ideal or robust testing scenario*, in your case this might be useful.

In the files where you think the error may be, starting with the first file which runs, add something like `exit('Here');`.
Then run the code and see if the new line is there before the exit message, if not the issue is after that `exit()`.

Delete the `exit()` from that file (make sure you do this!), then add it to the next file in the run order.
Run the code again, if no issue, repeat through the files in load order until the issue presents itself.

When the issue is present, you know the issue is between the code/file from the last time you exited and the current exit.
Examine that code carefully, the issue will be there.

Again, this is a little *tacky* and not a great test or debug method, but it can be helpful and sometimes necessary without a testing environment in place.

Also adding, as @Fred-ii- suggested, removing the `?>` tags at the end of PHP files can help, if you have them (in fact you shouldn't have them there, this used to be a requirement many moons ago but generally just causes issues/headaches).